# filter(String) also return number

Tags: javascript

can anyone explain me why `filter(String)` also return number?

```js
var arr = [1, "a", '7'],
    numArr = arr.filter(Number), // return 1, 7 (It's Ok)
    strArr = arr.filter(String); // Why return 1, a, 7

alert("numArr = " + numArr + "\n" + "strArr = " + strArr);
alert("typeof arr[0] = " + typeof arr[0]);
```

In the example above, `typeof arr[0]` is `number`; but why it's not filtered in`strArr`?

Thanks.

Comment: Because all `String` does is perform a `toString` conversion of its operand, so as long as the conversion is to a "truthy" value, it'll be included in the filter. In other words, it isn't doing an *"is it a string"* test. It's doing the string conversion and then doing a *"is it truthy"* test.

Comment: `Boolean(String(1)) -> Boolean("1") -> true`. `Boolean(Number("a")) -> Boolean(NaN) -> false`.

Comment: FYI -- there is no difference between the `""` and `''` style of quotes. They are both strings. JavaScript does not have a character type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.filter()` API passes each array element value to the function you provide. The value returned by that function is coerced to boolean and tested. Only `true` results are included in the returned array from `.filter()`.

The Number constructor interprets its argument as a number, and returns its value. When it is passed the string "a" by the `.filter()` mechanism, it returns `NaN`, which is interpreted as `false`.

The String constructor performs a similar operation, but the key difference is that just about anything makes a good valid string.  Thus, the number `1` in the array is returned as `"1"`, which when converted to boolean is `true` because it's a non-empty string.

To state that another way, it is **not** the case that the Number and String constructors perform any sort of yes/no identification of numeric or string values, so you can't use them to filter values in an array by type.

Answer (score 2):

Pointy's answer explains why you see this behaviour.

To achieve what it seems you want to do, you should use:

```
var arr = [1, "a", '7'],
    numArr = arr.filter(function(o) { return typeof(o) === "number"; }),
    strArr = arr.filter(function(o) { return typeof(o) === "string"; });
```

Comment: Assuming the array will only have primitive values (or that primitive wrapper objects should be excluded) and `NaN` should be counted as a number.